# nestjs 8.x.x version "Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'"? Problem

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs

I changed the versions of the following packages from 7.x.x to 8.4.6

```
"@nestjs/common": "~8.4.6",
"@nestjs/core": "~8.4.6",
"rxjs": "~7.5.5",
```

Then I started to have problems accessing the values I read from the constant.

```
export const DEFAULT_ENV_VALUES = {
  DEFAULT: {
    PORT: 8080,
    SERVER_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN_DELAY: 10000,
  },
};
```

Code snippet in main.ts:

```
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  enableGracefulShutdown({
    beforeDelay: configService.get<number>('SERVER_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN_DELAY'),
  });

  await app.listen(configService.get('PORT'));
}
```

[Error when accessing constant values in main.ts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQe3c.png)

error shown in terminal:

```
src/main.ts:36:44 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

   beforeDelay: configService.get<number>('SERVER_BEFORE_SHUTDOWN_DELAY'),
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/main.ts:46:38 - error TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.

  await app.listen(configService.get('PORT'));
                                        ~~~~~~

Found 2 error(s).
```

Comment: I googled "nestjs 8 breaking changes", does this help: https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#testingmodule--nestfactory

Comment: `ConfigService` came from `@nestjs/config`, then you need to show us the version of `@nestjs/config`

Comment: try `app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService)`

Comment: "@nestjs/config": "~0.5.0",
this line has solved
app.get<ConfigService>(ConfigService)
Thanks @MicaelLevi